# while-loop faster than for when returning iterator

Tags: performance, for-loop, while-loop, julia

I'm trying to oversimplify this as much as possible.

functions `f1`and `f2` implement a very simplified version of a [roulette wheel selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection) over a Vector `R`. The only difference between them is that `f1` uses a for and `f2` a while. Both functions return the index of the array where the condition was met.

`R=rand(100)`

```
function f1(X::Vector)
    l = length(X)
    r = rand()*X[l]
    for i = 1:l
        if r <= X[i]
            return i
        end
    end    
end

function f2(X::Vector)
    l = length(X)
    r = rand()*X[l]
    i = 1
    while true
        if r <= X[i]
            return i
        end
        i += 1
    end    
end
```

now I created a couple of test functions...
`M` is the number of times we repeat the function execution.

Now this is critical... I want to store the values I get from the functions because I need them later... To oversimplify the code I just created a new variable `r` where I sum up the returns from the functions.

```
function test01(M,R)
    cumR = cumsum(R)
    r = 0
    for i = 1:M
        a = f1(cumR)
        r += a
    end
    return r
end

function test02(M,R)
    cumR = cumsum(R)
    r = 0
    for i = 1:M
        a = f2(cumR)
        r += a
    end
    return r
end
```

So, next I get:

```
@time test01(1e7,R)
elapsed time: 1.263974802 seconds (320000832 bytes allocated, 15.06% gc time)

@time test02(1e7,R)
elapsed time: 0.57086421 seconds (1088 bytes allocated)
```

So, for some reason I can't figure out `f1` allocates a lot of memory and its even greater the larger `M` gets.
 I said the line `r += a` was critical, because if I remove it from both test functions, I get the same result with both tests, so no problems! So I thought there was a problem with the type of `a` being returned by the functions (because `f1` returns the iterator of the for loop, and `f2` uses its own variable `i` "manually declared" inside the function).

But...

```
aa = f1(cumsum(R))
bb = f2(cumsum(R))
typeof(aa) == typeof(bb)

true
```

So... what that hell is going on???

I apologize if this is some sort of basic question but, I've been going over this for over 3 hours now and couldn't find an answer... Even though the functions are fixed by using a while loop I hate not knowing what's going on.

Thanks.

Comment: Your functions are not deterministic.. both `f1` and `f2` contain `r = rand()*X[l]` and `r` is the stopping criterion. If you want to make the timings fair, pass `r` as a parameter and create a vector of different `r` to test the speed.

Comment: `f2` skips testing for the end of `X` vector. It saves time, but malcontent in `X` could cause Out of Bound exception. On the other hand `f1` can add an `@inbounds` before the `for` statement, as the index is sure to be inbound. These changes reduce the speed discrepancy between versions.

Comment: @DanGetz Thanks, I added `@inbounds` and the speed discrepancy was reduced, but the memory allocation problem still exists.

Comment: The type stability mentioned in the Answers is key as well. I solved it by adding a `return 0` at the end of `f1`. Additionally `for`s in `test0?` functions can be `@inbounds` too.

Comment: Thank you. That `return 0`did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see lots of surprising allocations like that, a good first thing to check is [type-stability](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#write-type-stable-functions).  The `@code_warntype` macro is very helpful here:

```
julia> @code_warntype f1(R)
# … lots of annotated code, but the important part is this last line:
  end::Union{Int64,Void}
```

Compare that to `f2`:

```
julia> @code_warntype f2(R)
# ...
  end::Int64
```

So, why are the two different?  Julia thinks that `f1` might sometimes return `nothing` (which is of type `Void`)!  Look again at your `f1` function: what would happen if the last element of `X` is NaN?  It'll just fall off the end of the function with no explicit return statement.  In `f2`, however, you'll end up indexing beyond the bounds of `X` and get an error instead.  Fix this type-instabillity by deciding what to do if the loop completes without finding the answer and you'll see more similar timings.

Comment: Fixing the type-stability doesn't account for everything, though, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thank you. I'm pretty sure this is the reason, although I don't fully understand why Julia thinks `f1` might return `nothing`. I mean... `X` is the cumsum of a Vector, so it will always be filled and ordered from minor to max, and my random `r` number at the most will be equal to the last value of `X`. I wouldn't know how to fix the type-stability honestly. :(

Comment: Try `test01(1e7, [R; NaN])` and `test02(1e7, [R; NaN])`. Julia cannot know if any elements of the vector are `NaN`, so it must generate code for both options. You can solve the type instability by simply putting an `error("not found")` in after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comment, your functions `f1` and `f2` both contain random numbers inside it, and you are using the random numbers as stopping criterion. Thus, there is no deterministic way to measure which of the functions is faster (doesn't depend in the implementation).

You can replace `f1` and `f2` functions to accept `r` as a parameter:

```
function f1(X::Vector, r)
    for i = 1:length(X)
        if r <= X[i]
            return i
        end
    end    
end

function f2(X::Vector, r)
    i = 1
    while i <= length(X)
        if r <= X[i]
            return i
        end
        i += 1
    end    
end
```

And then measure the time properly with the **same** `R` and `r` for both functions:

```
>>> R = cumsum(rand(100))
>>> r = rand(1_000_000) * R[end]  # generate 1_000_000 random thresholds

>>> @time for i=1:length(r); f1(R, r[i]); end;
0.177048 seconds (4.00 M allocations: 76.278 MB, 2.70% gc time)

>>> @time for i=1:length(r); f2(R, r[i]); end;
0.173244 seconds (4.00 M allocations: 76.278 MB, 2.76% gc time)
```

As you can see, the timings are now nearly identical. Any difference will be caused for external factors (warming or processor busy with other tasks).

Comment: Your timings miss the major cause of the performance difference since they don't do anything with the result of calling `f1`.  The non-determinacy isn't that big of a deal since the `text0X` function calls `fX` millions of times, which allows the non-determinacy in `rand()` to average out.

Comment: @MattB. Yep you are right on that. Was just timing *equivalent* `for` and `while` loops.